# Sandboxing turned on and is there a more Objective-C way to go about opening a com port?

Tags: objective-c, serial-port, appstore-sandbox

Right now I got the following class and its not working. It fails at the `open` call. I think this is because of sandboxing but I'm not sure how to move forward. Also this seems ver C like, is there a better more Objective-C (IOKIT?) way to fo this?

The device itself is a USB serial port.

Error given:

> Failed to open device: Operation not permitted

Current code:

```
#include <termios.h>
#import "Com.h"

#define BAUDCOUNT 17
speed_t baud_const[BAUDCOUNT] = { B50,    B75,    B110,   B134,   B150,   B200,
                                  B300,   B600,   B1200,  B1800,  B2400,  B4800, 
                                  B9600,  B19200, B38400, B57600, B115200 };
unsigned long baud_value[BAUDCOUNT] = { 50,   75,    110,   134,   150,   200,
                                        300,  600,   1200,  1800,  2400,  4800, 
                                        9600, 19200, 38400, 57600, 115200 };

@interface Com()
@property (assign) int fd;
@property (assign) struct termios oldio;
@end


@implementation Com
@synthesize fd = _fd;
@synthesize oldio = _oldio;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.fd = -1;
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (BOOL)open:(NSString*)device withBaud:(int)baud
{
    struct termios oldio;
    struct termios newtio;

    // Find the correct baud rate
    int baudid = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < BAUDCOUNT; i++) {
        if (baud_value[i] == baud) {
            baudid = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(baudid == -1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Invlaid baud rate: %d", baud);
        return NO;
    }

    // Open the device
    self.fd = open([device UTF8String], O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if (self.fd < 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to open device: %s", strerror(errno));
        return NO;
    }

    // Save old settings
    tcgetattr(self.fd, &oldio);
    self.oldio = oldio;

    // Init memory
    memset(&newtio, 0x00 , sizeof(newtio));
    cfmakeraw(&newtio);

    // settings flags
    newtio.c_cflag |= CS8;
    newtio.c_cflag |= CLOCAL;
    newtio.c_cflag |= CREAD;
    newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR | IGNBRK;
    newtio.c_oflag = 0;
    newtio.c_lflag = 0;

    // Timeout in 100ms
    newtio.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    // read 1 character
    newtio.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;

    // Setting baudrate
    cfsetispeed (&newtio, baud_const[baudid]);
    cfsetospeed (&newtio, baud_const[baudid]);

    // Flushing buffer
    tcflush(self.fd, TCIOFLUSH);

    // aplying new configuration
    tcsetattr(self.fd, TCSANOW, &newtio);

    return YES;
}
@end
```

Current Entitlements:

```
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.device.usb</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: You should check the output of `perror(3)` or whatever interface is more "native" to see _why_ the `open(2)` call failed.

Comment: @sarnold - "Operation not permitted" is the error which is a sandboxing thing.

Comment: .. or could be restricted to `root`?

Comment: @sarnold - Thankfully its not that bad. If I turn off sandboxing everything works. I just don't know how to make it work while sandboxed.

Comment: Which entitlements have you added to your `.entitlements` file?

Comment: @sarnold - Added to the post.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of Objective C frameworks for handling the serial port.

- [AMSerialPort](http://sourceforge.net/projects/amserial/)
- [SerialConnect](http://code.google.com/p/serialconnect/)

**Update:** It looks to me like you might need the `com.apple.security.device.serial` entitlement.  Despite the fact you are using a USB Serial adapter I believe the OS device drivers make all serial ports appear the same, i.e. not USB devices. I suspect the `com.apple.security.device.usb` entitlement that you do have doesn't apply to USB serial devices.

**Update 2:** I've just found this [Open Radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/9993340) from August last year which reports your problem. So it looks like the `com.apple.security.device.serial` entitlement doesn't work (or certainly didn't work back in August).

**Update 3:** If you do need to access the USB device directly (and assuming this works with the `com.apple.security.device.usb` entitlement) then you probably want to look at the IOSerialFamily source code which is available at http://opensource.apple.com/source/IOSerialFamily/IOSerialFamily-59/.

Source tarball: http://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/IOSerialFamily/IOSerialFamily-59.tar.gz

Comment: Internally these are both using the low level C api. Both will have the same sandboxing issue.

Comment: I don't believe you will find a library that won't have the sandboxing issue.  The only way to fix the sandboxing issue it to get the correct entitlement.  However, I'd be surprised if such an entitlement exists.  The entitlements that Apple have given us seem very limited.  My answer was really only intended to address your second question; a better Objective C way of dealing with the serial port.

Comment: Just had another look at the App Sandboxing documentation and there is a `com.apple.security.device.serial` entitlement which you don't list in your question above.  Have you tried this?

Comment: That entitlement doen't work either. I think I'm going to have to get the IOKit method to work.

Comment: :(  Looks like you may have to go the IOKit route, probably worth filing a radar and pointing at the Open Radar I posted above.  I've also included a link to the open source serial port driver source code on Apple's open source website which may provide some pointers on accessing the USB serial port device directly.

Comment: I just stumbled upon this, and I know it's old, but OS X 10.7.3 introduced the com.apple.security.device.serial entitlement, and it does work. I'm using in an app that uses AMSerialPort as well as an app that uses my own Objective-C serial port classes with no problems. There is a bug that causes sandbox violations, even with the entitlement when using Silicon Labs' USB to serial chipset/drivers, but other adapters work fine.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing some kernel programming which may be what you are wanting to do, but if you can use the IOKit then I do recommend that. In short doing anything with the kernel + sandboxing I simply do not recommend as you have found out.

The IOKit is another type of animal and really isn't too bad. Here is an example with a quick snippet that will disable the system from sleeping. This demonstrates how you can use the IOKit and I do believe it does work with a Sandboxed app.

```
    IOPMAssertionID assertionID;
    IOReturn err = IOPMAssertionCreateWithName(kIOPMAssertionTypeNoDisplaySleep, kIOPMAssertionLevelOn, CFSTR("Add Reason Here"), &assertionID);
    if ( err == kIOReturnSuccess ) {

        // Do stuff here while system is unable to sleep

        // Let the system resume ability to sleep
        err = IOPMAssertionRelease(assertionID);
    }
```

This documentation should also help: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/USBBook/USBDeviceInterfaces/USBDevInterfaces.html)

Note: "Important If your application is sandboxed, it must request the com.apple.security.device.usb entitlement in order to access USB devices."

Comment: I started to look into IOKit, but see my question here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184143/in-iokit-how-do-i-get-a-device-based-on-its-device-filename Basically now do I find the right device? If I can find the right device IOKit will be the way to go.

Comment: The AMSerialPort framework I suggest in my answer includes code to enumerate all the serial ports.  This library is based on IOKit if you want to see how it works.